# Cual es la forma correcta de agregar mas hojas de estilo en Laravel mix

Tags: php, javascript, css, laravel

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda como es la forma correcta de agregar mas hojas de estilo en laravel mix

Por ejemplo quiero agregar un css y un js de una plantilla que quiero usar entonces tengo este codigo para el css

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.combine([
 'resources/assets/theme/theme.min.css'
], 'public/css/themeall.css');
```

Si uso **mix.combine** se me combinara todos los **css** al archivo en la carpeta publica con el nombre themeall.css? es bueno hacer eso? o cual es la mejor opción o la mas optima para compilar o agregar mas archivos **css** y **js**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mix.combine(['resources/assets/theme/theme.min.css/*'], 'public/css/combined.css');
```

Básicamente se aplica al igual que en JS, solo que en JS tienes que tener cuidado en el orden en que se cargan los archivos.